# How is this move in swapping integral with summation justified?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Here's my justification for swapping an integral symbol (with finite limits) with an infinite summation:

**EDIT** after speaking with an MSE contributor, I think it is now apparent that the justification comes from the dominated convergence theorem.  I will edit to properly switch the limit symbol.  Please feel free to add any comments or suggestions.  Thanks.

For $|x|$<1,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} -1^{j+1} \int_0^1 x^{j-1}dx$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big (\sum_{j=1}^{n} -1^{j+1} \int_0^1 x^{j-1}dx \big )$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big ( \int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^{n} -1^{j+1} x^{j-1}dx \big )$$

(swapping symbols, since the integral is proper, i.e., has finite upper and lower limits, and the summation is finite -- up to n)

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big ( \int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^{n} -1^{j-1} x^{j-1}dx \big )$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big ( \int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^{n} -x^{j-1}dx \big )$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \big ( \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{n} -x^{j}dx \big )$$

$$= \big ( \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n} -x^{j}dx \big )$$

(taking the limit inside, by the **dominated convergence theorem**)

$$= \int_0^1 \frac {1}{1+x} dx$$

What do you think?  Does this look ok?  And, if it is ok, was it necessary for me to rewrite the infinite sum as a limit of a partial (finite) sum, in order to making the swapping valid?  Or, did I make several unnecessary moves in writing / moving the limit symbol around?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that the sequence of functions is actually dominated which is not hard (hint, just pick a constant function).

Comment: Hi @avid19 -- now that you mention it, for some reason I am having a hard time bounding the partial summations.  What would the constant function be?  We know that, for finite summation of a geometric series, the summation is $\large \frac { 1- r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.  Thanks,

Comment: It seems hard to bound for r close to 1 ... @avid19

Comment: oh, I think it's just bounded by the 1 function.  It would be +r on top and bottom of the partial sum formula...

Comment: Hi @avid19, I am curious about being able to use Fubini's theorem here.  It doesn't seem to work, if I check the condition that |f| has a finite integral / summation.  In our case here, |f|, in the beginning, would give the non-alternating harmonic series, which is not summable, so Fubini's theorem cannot be applied.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames You are right, I wasn't thinking. :)